# Croatian translation files not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, poedit

I’m trying to implement a multilanguage GDPR plugin. It works fine with English, Slovenian, Serbian and Italian language but I can’t get it to work with Croatian language. I’ve tried both -hr and -hr_HR locale to no avail. Has anyone had the problem with croatian .mo .po files not working? How did you solve the problem?
I use xili-language plugin for multilanguage support.

Comment: See answer by @yuraz here: [link]https://wordpress.org/support/topic/translation-not-working-63/   - "Rename files to gdpr-hr.po and gdpr-hr.mo and place them in \wp-content\languages\plugins"

Comment: I've tried that and no luck. So I have changed the slug to hr_hr and the plugin works. But now the whole page doesn't translate.. I guess there is a problem with the croatian code. I think it will be easyier to switch the whole page to hr_hr than forcing the plugin to work...